# fsevents optional dependency returns not compatible with system

Tags: babeljs, fsevents

Iam installing babel core 6.26.0 per [this documentation](https://blog.usejournal.com/creating-a-react-app-from-scratch-f3c693b84658), everything goes smoothly except for the following error:

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /babel-cli/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
```

I'm wondering if this is just noise? Or if there is a workaround someone might know of? I've seen some documentation around it but nothing concrete.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. `fsevents` is only supported on OSX, so on any other system you'll see a message that it has been skipped.

Comment: Okay that makes sense because I am on Ubuntu, thanks for the clarification